# how to get theta for a product of two orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $O(2)$ be the Lie group consists of all $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrices, i.e. all matrices such that their transpose is equal to their inverse. The operation is the usual product of matrices. It falls into two pieces; the matrices with determinant $1$ which forms a subgroup of $O(2)$ and the matrices with determinant $-1$. We can interpret the first case as a rotation by $\theta$ (where $\theta = 0$ is the identity), and the second as a reflection  of the identity across a line at an angle of $\theta/2$. So, we can express any orthogonal matrix in terms of $\theta$ where $\theta$ is between $0$ and $2\pi$.  My question is: if we have two reflection matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$, how to express the matrix $A_1A_2$ in terms of $\theta$? Of course $A_1A_2$ is a rotation matrix. Same thing how to get $\theta$ for the matrix which is the product of two rotation matrices; the product of a rotation matix with a reflection matrix.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [This page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of complex numbers, rotation by $\theta$ (counterclockwise) corresponds to multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$.  Reflection across the line at angle $\theta/2$ corresponds to rotation by $-\theta/2$ followed by complex conjugation followed by rotation by $+\theta/2$, i.e. $z \to e^{i\theta/2} \overline{e^{-i\theta/2} z} = e^{i\theta} \overline{z}$.  Two such reflections with $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ (in that order) give you $z \to e^{i\theta_2} \overline{e^{i\theta_1} \overline{z}} = e^{i(\theta_2 - \theta_1)} z$, i.e. rotation by $\theta_2 - \theta_1$.